# pandas long to wide format - splitting based on smaller vs larger value in column X

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with longitudinal data (two observations per individual), their age and score at each point. Currently, the df is in long format:

```
subj = ['subj1', 'subj1', 'subj2', 'subj2', 'subj3', 'subj3']
age = [37, 40, 56, 41, 27, 29]
score = [2,1,2,5,3,5]

pd.DataFrame(list(zip(subj, age, score)),
               columns =['subj', 'age', 'score'])
```

I would like to transform the df into wide format, where each subj is represented by a row, column 1 is the score at the younger age and column 2 is the score at older age.

| subjid | score_time1 | score_time2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| subj1 | 2 | 1 |
| subj2 | 5 | 2 |
| subj3 | 3 | 5 |

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html#pandas-series-sort-values) + [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) to create indicator `seq` then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot) with `seq` as the columns and [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html#pandas-dataframe-add-prefix) and clean up index and axes:

```
df['seq'] = df['age'].sort_values().groupby(df['subj']).cumcount() + 1
new_df = (
    df.pivot(index='subj', columns='seq', values='score')
        .add_prefix('score_time')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Or via [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table) to use series on-the-fly without affecting `df`:

```
new_df = (
    df.pivot_table(index='subj',
                   columns=df['age'].sort_values().groupby(df['subj']).cumcount() + 1,
                   values='score')
        .add_prefix('score_time')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

`new_df`:

```
    subj  score_time1  score_time2
0  subj1            2            1
1  subj2            5            2
2  subj3            3            5
```

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['subj', 'age'])
df = pd.concat([df1.iloc[::2,[0,2]].set_index('subj'), df1.iloc[1::2,[0, 2]].set_index('subj')], 1)
df.columns = ['score_time1', 'core_time1']
```

Alternative via `pivot_table` and `rank`:

```
df = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index='subj',
        columns=df.groupby('subj')['age'].rank(method='dense').astype(int),
        values='score')
    .add_prefix('score_time_')
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
    .reset_index()
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
      score_time1  core_time1
subj                          
subj1            2           1
subj2            5           2
subj3            3           5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also sort values and groupby with agg:

```
d = {'first':'score_time1','last':'score_time2'}
out = (df.sort_values(['subj','age']).groupby('subj')['score'].agg(['first','last'])
                                                .rename(d,axis=1).reset_index())
```

---

```
print(out)


    subj  score_time1  score_time2
0  subj1            2            1
1  subj2            5            2
2  subj3            3            5
```